# Pattern to not allow certain file names

Tags: python, glob

I'm reading some files from a directory which starts with 'buy_train_' and ends with 0.

```
data = [pd.read_parquet(f,engine='fastparquet') for f in glob.glob(local_data_path+'buy_train_20**-**-**_****_0')]
```

I need to update this regex expression so that it wouldn't include files with names starting from 'buy_train_2018', i.e., if the file has 2018 then bypass it. But I still need to filter out files basis the first regex expression, this is just another filter I want to be added.
Can anyone help me with this as I tried making an expression like below

```
buy_train_20**(?![8])-**-**_**_0
```

That should have filtered out anything which ends with 8, but it failed to do so.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit1:

Examples-

> buy_train_2020-01-08_001221_0
>
> buy_train_2020-05-02_067341_0
>
> buy_train_2020-07-26_011901_0

-> The above examples will be acceptable file names as they don't have 2018 after 'buy_train'.

> buy_train_2018-10-16_617901_0
>
> buy_train_2018-12-19_492111_0

-> The above examples should be filtered out as they have 2018 after 'buy_train'

Comment: Please add a handful or two of example file names, some of which should pass and some of which should not. Add an explanation next to each as to why it should or should not pass.

Comment: Tip: glob and regex are not the same.

Comment: I guess try using `^2018` this will return the string if it starts with 2018 or `2018$` so the string returns if it ends with 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First method with regex**

***(?!...)***

Matches if ... doesn’t match next. This is a negative lookahead assertion.

```
import re

regex_filter = 'buy_train_20(?!18)\d*-\d*-\d*_\d*_0'

expr1 = 'buy_train_2018-10-16_617901_0'
m = re.search(regex_filter, expr1)
print(m)
# None 
# (if None not do not try to print)

expr2 = 'buy_train_2020-01-08_001221_0'
m = re.search(regex_filter, expr2)
print(m)
print(m.group(0))
# <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 29), match='buy_train_2020-01-08_001221_0'>
# buy_train_2020-01-08_001221_0
```

**Second method with filter native function:**

But you don't necessarily need to use regex for filtering, just use for instance the native **filter** function as follows:

```
paths = ['buy_train_2020-01-08_001221_0',
         'buy_train_2020-05-02_067341_0',
         'buy_train_2020-07-26_011901_0',
         'buy_train_2018-10-16_617901_0',
         'buy_train_2018-12-19_492111_0']


prefix = 'buy_train_2018'

def function(path):
    if path[:len(prefix)] == prefix:
        return False
    else:
        return True

results = filter(function, paths)

for res in results:
    print (res)
    
# buy_train_2020-01-08_001221_0
# buy_train_2020-05-02_067341_0
# buy_train_2020-07-26_011901_0
```